# How can I delete entities belonging to a service path that I don't remember?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

When you want to delete an entity from Fiware Orion, you need to provide its ServicePath, Then how do you delete an item if you don't know its service path ?

[Other question more or less related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935182/retreive-fiware-servicepath-from-entitycontext-using-entityid) (How to retreive some entity's service path)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Orion API doesn't allow such operation directly, but as workaround you can know the service path to which an entity belongs with a query on the MongoDB database.

Let's assume the entity ID is `Room1`, entity the type is `Room` and you are using the default database name (i.e. `orion`), you can run the following command (in the same host where the MongoDB database runs).

```
echo 'db.entities.find({"_id.id": "Room1", "_id.type": "Room"}, {_id: 1})' | mongo orion --quiet
```

You will get a result like this one:

```
{ "_id" : { "id" : "Room1", "type" : "Room", "servicePath" : "/path" } }
```

The `servicePath` field specifies the entity service path (`/path` in the above example).